# Como comparar duas listas diferentes em Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho duas listas que compartilham de um valor em comum entre elas. Eu queria que que esses objetos selecionados fossem filtrados para que ele seja adicionado em um outra lista

```
List<Objeto1> lista1 = new ListaElementos1().getElementos();
List<Objeto2> lista2 = new ListaElementos2().getElementos();

List<Objeto1> destino = new ArrayList<>();



for(Objeto1 item : lista1){
    for(Objeto2 array: lista2){
        if(array.getId() == item.getId()){
            if(!destino.contains(item)){
                destino.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essa foi a forma que eu encontrei de fazer o filtro de forma que atendesse a minha necessidade. Porém eu não acho que essa é a melhor forma de fazer isso (por ter que rodar as duas listas inteiras para cada registro).

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso sem a necessidade de criar 2 laços de repetição?

Comment: As listas são iguais?

Comment: as que eu vou comparar não

Comment: A não ser que tenha algum requisito específico que não está na pergunta, não tem muito o que fazer. Pode ter alguma restrição que poderia permitir alguma otimização.

Comment: Eu pensei nessa pergunta baseado no atributo `Find` no C#. Ele aceita um lambda para filtrar esses registros e retorna um objeto da lista que atenda esse filtro. Eu não sei como ele faz isso numa `list`, se é um `for` dentro dele ou uma maneira mais otimizada. Talvez esse método seja tal qual eficiente mas com uma alta complexidade de compreensão. 

Sobre o requisito específico, eu recebo um Json que me manda qual grupo o item pertence (pelo id), e o outro objeto é uma lista de atributos relacionado a esse grupo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez seja isso o que você quer, mas de qualquer forma por debaixo dos panos ele rodará as duas listas.

Sou praticamente iniciante no Java e não tenho certeza se esta aqui é a melhor forma.

```
            List<Object1> arrayObj1 = Arrays.asList(
                                new Object1(1),
                                new Object1(2),
                                new Object1(3),
                                new Object1(4)
                            );

    List<Object2> arrayObj2 = Arrays.asList(
                                new Object2(4),
                                new Object2(5),
                                new Object2(6),
                                new Object2(7)
                            );

    //Array que receberá o resultado da comparação
    List<Object1> array2Obj1;

    array2Obj1 = arrayObj1.stream()
        .filter( o1 -> {
            return arrayObj2.stream()
                    .map(Object2::getId)
                    //Compara se o id do Object2 é igual ao id do Object1
                    .anyMatch(i2 -> i2.equals(o1.getId()));
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

   array2Obj1.stream().map(Object1::getId).forEach(System.out::println); // Result: 4
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando [stream](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/java/streams-api-java-8-3410098-ptb.html):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lista1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        List<String> lista2 = Arrays.asList("5", "6", "7", "8");

        List<Integer> interseccao = lista1.stream().filter(item1 -> {
            return lista2.stream().filter(item2 -> new Integer(item2).equals(item1)).findAny().isPresent();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(interseccao);
    }
}
```

Comment: Observação:  segundo o dono da pergunta, as listas são diferentes.

Comment: Listas diferentes: A=[1,2,3,4], B=[1,2,3,4,5,6,54,100000,12,-1]. Entendes? Ou seja, a quantidade de elementos é diferente.

Comment: Aqui, os elementos até podem ser diferentes, que podem ser facilmente convertidos, mas a quantidade de elementos são iguais. ``List<Integer> lista1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
        List<String> lista2 = Arrays.asList("5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");``

Comment: Apesar de o número de elementos das lista não fazer diferença, alterei no exemplo a quantidade de elementos.